# The custom of putting the first snow on forehead?

Tags: sources-mekorot, snow, minhag

In yeshiva, I saw that the Rabbis had a custom to put (the first) snow on their forehead.

What is the source of this custom?
This was in Jerusalem.

Comment: What is "the first snow"? Like, does that mean the first snow of the year?

Comment: @ezra yes, that is how i understood it

Comment: @ezra it is not clear to me if it needs to be the first, or the first that stuck

Comment: It’s a [Lurianic] kabbalatic *segulah* for remembering Torah (like wine from havdalah...) and *yirat shamayim*.

Comment: @Oliver source please what i know about it is end of halacha 5 here https://www.chabad.org/3447087/#footnoteRef20a3447087 (where footnote says it is good for sight)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is such an idea from the Arizal that if one wants a segulah for a good memory they should place snow on their forhead since the gematria for (שלג(333 is the same number value as the word( שכחה(333. Don't remember such a thing that it has to be first snow.

I just found in the Segulas Yisrael this idea of first snow from the Kanfei Yonah [image]

Comment: In Jerusalem there's very rarely a second snow.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe first snow ("that falls on the ground" (see his edit)) means the first millimeters, and not the next ones

Comment: How does putting forgetfulness שכחה on your head help with memory?? IMHO the head should be protected from all snow. (Not a bad idea in any case.)

Comment: @Avrohom this is the first kabbalistic segulah that you don't understand how it works? I don't know how any of it is supposed to work.

Comment: @DoubleAA You're right but I'd forgotten about the others through the summer.